# Does the iPad Pro M2 (4th generation) support 6 GHz Wi-Fi?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

I’m confused! Does the iPad Pro M2 (4th generation) support 6 GHz?

It’s mentioned on this [kbase](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT213433):

> “Wi-Fi 6E uses the 6 GHz wireless band to enable faster and more reliable wireless connections on supported devices. Here's how to get the best wireless performance when using Wi-Fi 6E with an Apple device.”

But on the iPad’s [specs page](https://www.apple.com/uk/ipad-pro/specs/) it’s mentioned:

> “Wi‑Fi 6E (802.11ax) with 2x2 MIMO, simultaneous dual band (2.4GHz and 5GHz)”

I only have two WiFi 6 « E » clients for now but I want to use the 6 GHz band with an Unifi Entreprise AP.

Comment: What is meant by "« E »"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the iPad Pro M2 (4th generation) support 6Ghz Wi-Fi?

The short answer is yes, it supports 6GHz Wi-Fi.

Basically, Wi-Fi 6E is compatible with Wi-Fi 6 and legacy standards that already operate in the 2.4 and 5GHz ranges.  What the spec page is referencing that the iPad can do two simultaneous streams using both the 2.4GHz radio and the 5GHz radios.

From [Network World](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2278668/mimo--antennas-and-streams---oh--my-.html):

> 2x2 MIMO, for example, indicates two antennas at the transmit end and 2 antennas at the receive end, the minimum required by the draft 802.11n standard.

Comment: Thank you! after reading the product page I thought it was a limited version of WiFi 6E without the actual 6 GHz band, which I want (I'm using a UniFI U6-Enterprise, and I want to use the 6GHZ spectrum).

Comment: Upgrading  my own Unifi APs to 6E is on my list so I was researching this very topic the other day.  Glad I could assist!